# Can't verify if label text is blank

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am trying to do something fairly simple, but I can't get it figured out.  I have a label that is populated based on an alert controller action.  I am trying to create an alert that will pop up if the user did not select an option to populate the label text.  Every time I run the app it moves to the next view without popping up the alert.  Can someone help me?

My code:

```
@IBAction func lookingfor(sender: AnyObject) {



    if self.iamalabel.text!.isEmpty

    {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "here2", message:
        "Oops... you missed something!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Try Again", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))


        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }
    else

    {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use .isEmpty,

instead, check the value of the text

```
if (self.yourLabel.text == "" || self.yourLabel.text == nil) { }
```